# Slug function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, slug

in my website, I have a `slug` function in JavaScript. Which will replace all the special character except `@` inn the string with `-`. It works. but not giving the desired output. What is wrong with the code?

My function is

```
function to_slug(string) {
    var new_str = string.trim().replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z@]+/i, '-').toLowerCase();
    return new_str;
}
```

This function works for first two `space` strings. that is,

`sample shop` will give output `sample-shop`

but

`sample shop hfnbbf` giving output as `sample-shop hfnbbf`

and

`sample shop hfnbbf.hgdsf` giving output as `sample-shop hfnbbf.hgdsf`

Whay this is happening? please help me.. Thanks in advance

Comment: `replace` only replaces the first occurrence, respecting the regular expression basically. You need to use the `/g` flag for it to "globally" replace all occurrences.

Comment: "_This function works for first two `space` strings._" What does this mean? All three of your examples just show the function doing nothing at all to the input.

Comment: @JLRishe : sorry.. I edited the question

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv I would just post that as an answer before someone else walks away with the "honor".